# How to add prerequisites for JRE using Wix Installer?

Tags: wix

Currently my installer is able to check whether the JRE is installed in my machine or not but, I want my .msi installer to install the JRE as prerequisites automatically. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by using an EXE bootstrapper. Here are some how-to's which may help you:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/redistributables_and_install_checks_toc.htm

WiX doesn't support prerequisites in MSI packages, it needs the EXE bootstrapper.